# Merge columns that are empty with ones with values and merge it into one row in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

There are a lot of different questions about merging rows to one, but I couldn't find one for my example below when I use sub select queries. I tried to aggregate with group by, but could not make it work.

For one ID I get three results in different columns and rows. How can I combine these results, by selecting the max value of each column for each ID and put in one row?

My current code below

```
SELECT MMITNO, (SELECT COFA WHERE ALUN='PCE' and DMCF='2') as EAperCSE, (SELECT COFA WHERE ALUN='PAL' and DMCF='1') as CSEperPAL, (SELECT COFA WHERE ALUN='LAY' and DMCF='1') as CSEperLAY, CSEperPAL/CSEperLAY as LAYperPAL 
FROM MVXJDTA.MITMAS LEFT JOIN MVXJDTA.MITAUN on MUITNO=MMITNO
```

My current result

[image]

What I would like achieve as a first step is

```
MMITNO EAperCSE CSEperPAL CSEperLAY
10445  18       16        4
10446  27       40
```

A second step would be to add a calculated field, but I just get an error when I do this

```
MMITNO EAperCSE CSEperPAL CSEperLAY LAYperPAL (calculated column CSEperPal/CSEperLAY)
10445  18       16        4         4
10446  27       40
```

Any thoughs how I can do this?

Comment: what's your DBMS ?

Comment: I use WINSQL Professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select mmitno, 
    max(case when alun = 'pce' and dmcf = '2' then cofa end) as eapercse, 
    max(case when alun = 'pal' and dmcf = '1' then cofa end) as cseperpal, 
    max(case when alun = 'lay' and dmcf = '1' then cofa end) as cseperlay, 
    max(case when alun = 'pal' and dmcf = '1' then cofa end) / max(case when alun = 'lay' and dmcf = '1' then cofa end) as layperpal 
from mvxjdta.mitmas mm
left join mvxjdta.mitaun ma on muitno = mmitno
group by mmitno
```

I strongly recommend prefixing *all* column names in the query with the (alias of the) table they belong to, so the query is not ambiguous.

Comment: Many thanks GMB. I didn't know how to use case in SQL, so I learned something new today. It works like a charm!